# the meaning of "as best as"

Tags: meaning

Source: https://www.poetryfoundation.org/articles/69750/when-youre-strange

> It was, as best as I can recall, the first time I listened to a poet speak.

Not sure how to understand the phrase "as best as" in the context. Does the phrase have the same meaning as "as far as"?

Comment: The speaker is hedging. There is less than perfect confidence in the recollection.  "as far as" is a decent paraphrase.

Comment: You might want to read this article: http://articles.chicagotribune.com/2006-01-11/features/0601100366_1_phrase-cambridge-university-press-grammatical [by the way, for me, as best as I can recall, is adverbial,but never mind me. :)]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although on the surface it might seem like the two expressions mean pretty much the same thing, they're actually not exactly the same. My feeling is that **as best as** in meaning would be somewhat similar to the expression [**to the best of one's ability**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/to-the-best-of-someone-s-ability) (but I don't think they're completely interchangeable) and, with regard to the actual phrase in question, to the expression [**to the best of one's recollection**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/to-the-best-of-my-recollection). It has the nuance that there is a mental or physical effort involved on the speaker's part when they're trying to do something. **as far as** doesn't seem to have that distinction. It just means *to the extend that*. So, when you say something like *As far as I know, Bolivia is a country in South America*, this implies that you don't have to think hard to recall that fact because it's in the range of your immediate knowledge. The act of recalling, on the other hand, typically requires some mental exertion to be done before you can say something for certain.